# How do I fill down the rest of a column in the next available cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am using the following code for assigning a value.

```
    Sheets("CDGL Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Formula= "April"
```

I need the `"April"` to fill down to the rest of my adjacent rows in blank Cells among the Cells that have values in them.

Example:
`Cell A899` is blank, `Cell B899` has a value, `Cell C899` has a value
`"April"` needs to be put into that blank `cell A899`.

Please help!

Comment: What software or coding language are you using. We need more information in the question and in the tags.

Comment: This is VBA in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Dim lStartRow             As Long
Dim lEndRow               As Long
With Sheets("CDGL Data")
    lStartRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lEndRow = Application.Max(.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Range(.Cells(lStartRow, "A"), .Cells(lEndRow, "A")).Value2 = "April"
End With
```

Comment: For more tips on finding the last row, I suggest looking over [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)